# what are nodejs app entry files like app.js, server.js or index.js for a developer coming from a ruby on rails environment?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, express

I have been coding with Ruby on Rails for the past 3 years. I find it very comprehensive and self-explanatory. However, When I started getting into NodeJS. I noticed some inconsistencies as to how I was used to handling things back in RoR. one of which is the app entry file [serverjs OR app.js OR index.js] in Node. I am wondering what exactly are they? I mean I get that they are starting the server. but why do I see some people requiring libraries and using middlewares in this file. should this be a file calling all functions defined elsewhere in our app? I am very curious to know this in detail.

Any help or guidance towards resources would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby on Rails, you start the server by running the `rails` command line -- an off the shelf program. `rails` looks in the conventional places (e.g. your config, your routes, etc.) to initialize your application. It runs your application with the `ruby` executable which interprets your `.rb` files.

> Rails: `bash` (you, on terminal) → `rails server` (cli) → `ruby` (interpreter) → your code

On the other hand, with a Node express app, you don't run a program that runs `node` -- you run node itself. `node server.js` starts a Node process which executes your code.

> Express: `bash` (you, on terminal) → `node server.js` (interpreter) → your code.

With Rails, the framework calls your code (which it identified by looking in the conventional places). With Node Express apps, your code calls Express.

It's conventional in the Node world to bundle a web app tool as a library (like express or react). However, many web app tools (like react) also provide an optional command line interface (like [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)) which provide an entrypoint for the app like `rails server`.

Comment: Another key difference is that Rails is built on top of the Rack CGI and `rails server` is really just a wrapper around the `rackup` command.

Comment: That's a nicely put and explained answer. It makes perfect sense. But what exactly goes into `server.js` in terms of Node? I get that we have to include all the routes that we defined in routes folder. what else has a place in `server.js` that is essential for the running of our application?

Comment: Ah, I think that's outside the scope of this question. It sounds like you're looking for "what are all the parts of an express app that I need to include in `server.js`" or something like that. Have you gone through Express js overviews or tutorials, or read through the Express docs? There is a lot of material on that topic so I'm probably not going to add anything.

Or, if you have a specific node file that's not doing what you think it ought to, you could ask a new question. Make sure to include an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example